# Is the code in git branches actually stored locally or on github?

Tags: git, github, branch

I see where references to branches are stored locally, as it shows in this image below, but when i open a branch it just has the commit SHA in it, not the actual code for that branch.

[image]

So does the SHA just point to where the code for that branch is actually stored on GitHub? My friend noted that when you delete a branch on GH it still seems to be available locally, so maybe it is stored locally?

I did look around for other answers to this, saw some useful info like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555221/where-are-files-for-local-branches-stored) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586979/how-are-different-branches-stored-locally-from-git-on-my-disk/53588558#53588558) on stack overflow, but none of them quite answered this Q for me)

Comment: Git stores all your data locally.

Comment: Oh thanks @larsks, do you have a sense of where or how it is stored locally? Maybe i should revise my Q to ask that...sorry newer to posting on stack overflow, not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+does+git+store+files

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects